# Application's production version won't render in IE

Tags: angular, sharepoint

In a SharePoint environment, I am using an Angular 5 application that works fine in Chrome but not using IE11. Using `ng serve`, I can run the app fine in IE in the dev mode. Going down the DOM tree I was able to find the info related to the app. It is pulling in the correct files but there is nothing inside of `app-root`.

```
<div class="ms-rtestate-field">
  <title>Ng5barcode</title>
  <base href="https://test.com/_catalogs/masterpage/Custom/ng5qrcode/dist/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="styles.ac89bfdd6de82636b768.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <app-root></app-root> <!--NOTHING INSIDE APP-ROOT-->
  <script src="inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="polyfills.e984deee4b28eb49ced8.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="main.18d7e665679bb3e9b30e.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

The polyfill file looks like:

```
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: 0 Errors in console.

Comment: There is possibility  that you are emulating old IE, you need to look on your console, what kind of ie its emulating. I had this problem on my corporative PC?

Comment: How do I find this info?